# Azure Functions app 4 is giving access denied when starting with func host start --useHttps --cors

Tags: azure, azure-functions

`func host start --useHttps --cors * --cert certificatename.pfx --password certificatepassword` is giving access denied error

```
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5530
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.5.21962

Warning: Proxies are not supported in Azure Functions v4. Instead of 'proxies.json', try Azure API Management: https://aka.ms/AAfiueq
Access denied
```

What is the cause of this issue

I have tried by removing proxies also
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please share your function code?

Comment: This code doesn't seem like Azure function NodeJS code. Have you used Function App extension in vs code to create the function?

Comment: Also please share your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You can either follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript,windows,azure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v3) or use the steps below to create a NodeJS function in vs code-

1. Install the Azure Function extension in vs code.

[image]

2. Create the NodeJS function by following the template.

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Your folder should look like below. Please note in my case, I have added the certificate explicitly.

[image]

4. I have below codes in the mentioned files.

**index.js**-

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
```

**local.settings.json**-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

I am executing my function using the command `func host start --useHttps --cors * --cert <certificate_name>.pfx --password <certificatepassword>` and able to get expected response as shown below-

[image]

[image]